# How to Elementwise Sum a Sequence of DenseVectors in Breeze

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I have a sequence of `DenseVector[Double]` and I would like to sum them elementwise to get a single `DenseVector[Double]`.  Is there an easy built-in way of doing this in the Breeze Scala library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` function and add all the vectors together, as `+` is defined as [Elementwise Addition](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstart) for `DenseVectors`:

```
val dv = DenseVector[Double](1,2,3)

List(dv, dv, dv).reduce(_ + _)
// res0: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(3.0, 6.0, 9.0)

Seq(dv, dv, dv).reduce(_ + _)
// res1: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(3.0, 6.0, 9.0)
```